# How to add multi levels, into responsive css menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Before you guys yell on me,
I know there are tons of questions about this and I saw a few nice complete menus too.

But mine looks very simple to me, Might be cause I am using it for a long time, same as gf.lol

> At the moment my menu has 2 levels but I want to do it multi level

I tried several solution but couldnt make it work, I am very bad on css.
Here is the fiddle I do tests on there: https://jsfiddle.net/Netmaster/14gcz7bk/

Here my codes:

```js
$("nav div").click(function() {
  $("ul").slideToggle();
  $("ul ul").css("display", "none");
});
// $("ul li").click(function(){
//     $("ul ul").slideUp();
//     $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
// });
$('ul li').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings().find('ul').slideUp();
  $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 768) {
    $("ul").removeAttr('style');
  }
});
```

```css
nav div {
  padding: 0.6em;
  background: #e3e3e3;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #292929;
  font-size: 24px;
}

nav ul li i {
  color: #292929;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #e3e3e3;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a {
  padding: 15px;
  color: #292929;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: lightgrey;
}

ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: auto;
  background: lightgrey;
  display: none;
}

ul ul li {
  display: block;
  background: #e3e3e3;
}

ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  nav div {
    display: block;
  }
  ul {
    display: none;
    position: static;
    background: #e3e3e3;
  }
  ul li {
    display: block;
  }
  ul ul {
    position: static;
    background: #e3e3e3;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div>
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Vanilla JavaScript</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ReactJS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">VueJS</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Graphic Design <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Font</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PSD</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Illustration</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Texture</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call stopPropagation() method in order to prevent the first level to close, while closing the second level:

```
$('ul li').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: I did like this `$('ul li').click(function () {
  $(this).siblings().find('ul').slideUp();
  $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
 });` that it works fine thanks, need to convert it to multilevel menu, that is the problem for my css knowledge :) no need to stay open, clicking a link will redirect to a page.